# VS Code: No PHP executable is set

Tags: files, php, paths, visual-studio-code

I am busy with a Udemy course about WordPress. The course uses VS Code as text editor and I love it, but keep getting a "No PHP executable is set error". PHP was loaded as part of the Local-by-Flywheel software, so I do not know where to find the executable. What command can I use in the terminal to find the path of this file (I don't even know what the PHP executable is called.
Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd try `ls /usr/bin/ | grep php*`.

Comment: I get the following: :~$ ls /usr/bin/ | grep php*
h2ph
pphs
wpa_passphrase
Xephyr
:~$                Still no path or the file. My knowledge of using the Linux terminal is very rudimentary so please be patient with me. Thank you very much for your answer

Comment: According to [this page](https://gist.github.com/keesiemeijer/a888f3d9609478b310c2d952644891ba), it could be `/usr/local/bin/phpunit`. Not really sure which steps you've followed, also, it seems unrelated to Ubuntu. Good luck anyway.

Comment: I figured it out. Local-by-Flywheel is a binary installation so there is no executable as such. The solution was to install the same version of PHP that Local uses and then to use that path which was simply /bin/php7.4. The error notification is now resolved on VS Code. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: this command will help you "sudo apt-get install php"